# Query Efficiency - Count

Tags: mysql, performance, count

I'm trying to get a query to run more efficiently and to return valid results. My current query takes more than 10 minutes to complete when I include the COUNT function on a specific column. I have also noticed when doing the count all results are returned as NULL.

When I run the COUNT part on it's own, it takes less than a second to complete and I get the correct result.

Here is the query I am using:

```
 SELECT 
    x.entityCode 'Entity Code'
,   (SELECT MAX(visit_date) AS secMaxDate FROM z_dev.entities_visited 
            WHERE entity_code = x.entityCode AND visit_date < x.maxDate) ' Previous Visit Date'
,   x.maxDate   'Latest Visit Date'
,   cycle_end_date 'Cycle End Date'
,   total_visits 'Total Visits (28 Days)'
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        entity_code AS storeCode
    ,   MAX(visit_date) AS maxDate
    ,   MAX(cycle_end_date) AS cycle_end_date
    ,   (SELECT COUNT(visit_date) FROM z_dev.entities_visited A
            WHERE visit_date BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 28 DAY)) AND DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY) AND A.entity_code = B.entity_code)
            GROUP BY entity_code) AS 'total_visits'
    FROM 
        z_dev.entities_visited B GROUP BY entity_code) AS X;
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
entity_code | visit_date | cycle_end_date   
------------+------------+--------------- 
108792      |2016-12-07  |2016-12-11    
108793      |2016-12-08  |2016-12-11    
108795      |2016-12-06  |2016-12-11    
108796      |2016-12-05  |2016-12-11    
108795      |2016-12-13  |2016-12-18    
108792      |2016-12-14  |2016-12-18    
108793      |2016-12-14  |2016-12-18    
108796      |2016-12-16  |2016-12-18



   Field            | Type      | Key   
    ----------------+-----------+--------------- 
    entity_code     |bigint(10) |MUL  
    visit_date      |date       |    
    cycle_end_date  |date       |MUL
```

The count of the total visits is a part I have added to the query solution I was assisted with yesterday. Basically what I would like to see is the following three things:

- When was the last date the entity was visited (Currently given by
  x.maxDate)
- When was the entity last visited prior to the most recent
  visit (Currently given by 'Previous Visit Date')
- How many times was the entity visited in the last 28 days

CURRENT ISSUES EXPERIENCED / OUTCOMES

- Slow Query Time (10 minutes +)
- Count as subquery returns all NULL Values
- Count query run on it's own returns expected results in a few seconds
- Primary query returns expected result in a few seconds

Comment: It would be helpful if you could let us know what you are trying to calculate.  Your current query looks inefficient and is messy.  Maybe we can give you an alternative which would perform better too.

Comment: Gut reaction says to make sure you have an index `(entity_code, visit_date DESC)` on `entities_visited`, but as for all performance problems, can you post the current indexes you have and the results of an `EXPLAIN` on your query?

Comment: Thanks guys, I added some additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I think I was over thinking the problem which is why I wasn't getting the desired result.

I now have my query running as expected.

```
SELECT 
    x.entityCode 'Entity Code'
,   (SELECT MAX(visit_date) AS secMaxDate FROM z_dev.entities_visited 
            WHERE entity_code = x.entityCode AND visit_date < x.maxDate) ' Previous Visit Date'
,   x.maxDate   'Latest Visit Date'
,   cycle_end_date 'Cycle End Date'
,   visits 'Total Visits (28 Days)'
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        entity_code AS entityCode
    ,   MAX(visit_date) AS maxDate
    ,   MAX(cycle_end_date) AS cycle_end_date
    ,   (SELECT COUNT(visit_date) AS visits WHERE visit_date BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 28 DAY)) AND DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))) AS visits
    FROM 
        z_dev.entities_visited B GROUP BY entity_code) AS X
GROUP BY
    x.entityCode;
```